# Parse config file without executing it

Tags: django, parsing, config

I need to get every definitions from a django config file without executing/sourcing the file.

Ideally I want to be able to get:

```
# common.py
DJANGO_ROOT = ...
DEBUG = ...
```

Return value :

```
-> ("DJANGO_ROOT", "DEBUG", ...)
```

Through this I want to compare different config file to check if all variable are defined first in `common`.

I am currently trying with the `compiler.parseFile` method but I saw that the package is deprecated.

Is there another way to do?

Comment: What's your end goal? Can you not just use `from django.conf import settings`?

Comment: Test if a config file has no new definition (i.e. everything in `dev.py` is defined in `common.py`)